# How to Fake my Location for all APPs installed?

Tags: android, mocking

Hi guys i'm trying to fake my gps location with mock but it seems to work only in my own app, is there any way i do this for all my apps, like the google maps app?

thx..

My current class seems like it:

```
lm = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        myLocation = lm.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
        if (myLocation != null) {
            x = myLocation.getLatitude() + 0.001; //velocidade
            y = myLocation.getAltitude();
        } else {

        }

        final String providerName = "MyFancyGPSProvider";
        lm = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
//Remember to remove your your provider before using it or after.
//In other case it won't be remove till restarting the phone.
        if (lm.getProvider(providerName) != null) {
            lm.removeTestProvider(providerName);
        }
        lm.addTestProvider(providerName, true, false, false, false, true, true, true,
                Criteria.POWER_LOW, Criteria.ACCURACY_FINE);
        lm.setTestProviderEnabled(providerName, true);
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            return;
        }
        lm.requestLocationUpdates(providerName, 0, 0, this);


        // Click listener for W KEY BUTTON
        bt1.button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                x += 1.001;
                Location loc = new Location(providerName);
                loc.setLatitude(x);
                loc.setLongitude(y);
                loc.setAltitude(0);
                loc.setAccuracy(10f);
                loc.setElapsedRealtimeNanos(System.nanoTime());
                loc.setTime(System.currentTimeMillis());
                lm.setTestProviderLocation(providerName, loc);

            }
        });
```

Every time a button is pressed. it adds +1 to my current position, and the **onLocationChanged** is fired with the new position correctly but it doesn't change anything on the official google maps app

```
@Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        if(location != null) {
            Log.w("WalkGPS", "lat = " + location.getLatitude() + " long = "+location.getLongitude());
        }
    }
```

Comment: PS:  it need to make an app similar too :https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.fly.gps&rdid=com.fly.gps

Comment: No there isn't.  There's mock location, which is what your link looks like it uses.  But that will only effect apps that have the mock location permissions and use GPS (mock doesn't effect network location).  Most release apps do not listen to mock.  I'm not sure if Google Play Services location providers listen to mock.

Comment: my application already have the mock location permissions, i just want to make the google maps app show the position i'm telling like the above link does

Comment: And that's not going to happen.  Google Maps does not use the mock permissions, because they don't want a rogue mock provider confusing normal users who don't know that mock locations even exist.

Comment: Im not actually saying i want to do this only with mock, i just used it and didnt work, right now i have no idea how can i sove this problem, isn't there any other way?

Comment: Yes, I'm saying there isn't another way.  Or at least not one short of a custom firmware

Comment: Thats too bad, so that app probably uses something very custom huh? thx..

Comment: That app uses mock-  its why they require you to turn on mock locations in the instructions.  Its also why it has such a low rating and so many 1 stars-  it doesn't work in most apps.  You can also see mock in its list of permissions.

Comment: yeah, my app is on that list, i tried that app and it works on my cellphone so it is possible somehow, now i just have to figured out :D

Comment: Most of the good app which have their core feature based on location, check if the user send mock location. it's really easy to do. If the user send mock position then they just ignore it or block you from using the feature. It will work for some app and doesn't for some other smart app. and you have no way to fake those good app that check if the location is mocked

Comment: Ohhh, so it only Works for a phew apps, makes all sence now, thats Good to know, ty guys for all info.